# HIVE WHERE NOT EXISTS doesn't compare NULLS

Tags: sql, hive, hql, hiveql

I am trying to select only the rows where some of the column values differ. My problem is that if I use =, it doesn't compare columns with null values and if I replace = with Like, I get the following error, Any suggestions? Both tables have columns that are equivalent

> Unsupported SubQuery Expression SubQuery expression refers to both Parent and SubQuery expressions and is not a valid join condition. (state=42000,code=10249)

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 t
where not exists(
select * from table2 l where t.loco_id=l.loco_id and
t.a=l.a and
t.b=l.b
);
```

Comment: **(1)**  Add a data sample including required results **(2)** Which column might be NULL? a? b?  loco_id? all of them? some of them?

Answer (score 1):

```
select  t.* 

from                table1 t

        left join   table2 l 

        on          t.loco_id   <=> l.loco_id 
                and t.a         <=> l.a 
                and t.b         <=> l.b

where   l.loco_id is null
;
```

> **A <=> B**
>   Returns same result with EQUAL(=) operator for non-null
>   operands, but returns TRUE if both are NULL, FALSE if one of the them
>   is NULL. (As of version 0.9.0.)
>
> https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-RelationalOperators

Answer (score 0):

`null` is technically means its `unknown`

`=` doesn't compare `unknown`-s; because its impossible to compare them...the result of the comparision of two `unknowns` is `unknown`:

```
select assert_true( (null = null) is null  )
```

however:

```
select assert_true( (null = null) )
```

will fail, because the result is `unknown`(null).

If you still want to join by using `null`-s; I would recommend to add some `coalesce`-s to get rid of these `unknown`-s.